# Can I package DNX in my VS2015 project?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, dnx

I had the impression that a web project could contain a specific version of DNX.  I assumed that means the actual DNX runtime files would be included within the project folder structure.  Is that true?  I'm trying to create an automated build for my project but it's failing because the build server does not have DNX installed.  I was hoping not to have to install DNX on the build server - it should all be handled by the project.

Am I completely wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I've written a blog post about .NET Core and CI - http://www.pyrzyk.net/dotnet-core-and-continuous-integration-with-appveyor .

In summary, you have to install DNVM and DNX runtime on the machine. Before the build run dnu restore / dotnet restore command.